# Removing Tkinter titlebar and window border?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i have a questionn about Tkinter window boarders.
I'm trying to basically remove them.

I searched all around Stack Overflow (here) and other websites
on how do i remove them, and all i found is:
`root.overrideredirect(True)`,
`root.attributes("-type", "dock")`,
and `root.attributes("-type", "splash")` but,
they all have the same problem.
The problem is that they all remove the icon and the title from the taskbar.
With `root.overrideredirect(True)`, the window cannot be minimized with `root.iconify()` or `root.state("iconic")`.

Is there something that i could maybe do with it, or should i start learning something else like PyQt5 or Kivy?

Comment: I don't know how You are trying to minimize Your window but if You are calling a function You could add to it `.overrideredirect(False)` before calling `.iconify()`

Comment: @Matiiss I tried that and for some reason it didn't work in my linux system